# Почему не работает REST controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Создаю Spring-приложение со следующей структурой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и деплою его на сервере томкэт

После деплоя открывается index страница, но не могу попасть к контролллеру по url:
`localhost:8080/test`

**код контроллера:**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Tst {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getTest(){
        System.err.println("========IN REST MESSAGE OKEY==========");
        System.err.println("========IN REST MESSAGE OKEY==========");
        System.err.println("========IN REST MESSAGE OKEY==========");
        System.err.println("========IN REST MESSAGE OKEY==========");
    }
}
```

**`web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<display-name>GameShop</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**`applicationContext.xml`:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocaion="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       default-autowire="byName">
    
    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

**и `web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скорее всего у вас приложение не задеплоено в рут. Попробуйте сделать реквест таким образом: localhost:8080/{ваше_имя_war_файла_в_томкате}/test

Comment: а какой вообще респонс вы получаете?

Comment: @DimaKhodan  404 not found

Comment: @aleshka-batman  Нужно ли как-то специальным образом инициализировать контекс?

Comment: Нет , не нужно. Просто посмотрите какой контекс паф у вашего приложения. Это можно сделать через томкат админ или гляньте в webapps.

Comment: описан ли в web.xml applicationContext ?

Comment: @Denis описан, обновил описание вопроса.

Comment: Добавьте applicationContext.xml и web.xml а то так годать можно долго. Вобще я думаю тут два вариант либо вы в web.xml что то не првавильно настроили, к примеру не добавили ContextLoaderListener, либо в applicationContext забыли что то прописать к примеру <context:annotation-config />. Кроче годать можно долго....

Comment: @Denis добавил.

Answer (score 0):

[3.10.2. Автоматическое определение классов и регистрация определений компонентов](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s10.html#beans-scanning-autodetection)

> Spring может автоматически обнаруживать стереотипные классы и
>   регистрировать соответствующие `BeanDefinitions` с помощью
>   `ApplicationContext`

---

добавьте в конфигурацию спринга

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.rest" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в web.xml

```
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```